# Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am mking an android app in which i am making dynamically table rows and then adding imageviews and textviews to it dynamically.
It adds the first row and then give the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I am using the following code for it:

```
          ar1= new JSONArray(children.toString());
                                for(int mn=0;mn<ar1.length();mn++){
                                    value=ar1.getString(mn);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog.this);
                                    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tr.setId(100+mn);
                                    tr.setMinimumHeight(60);
                                    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                    TextView child= new TextView(HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog.this);
                                    child.setId(200+mn);
                                    child.setHeight(50);
                                    child.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                    child.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    System.out.println(value);
                                    child.setText(value);
                                    System.out.println("adding iv");
                                    tr.addView(iv,0);
                                    System.out.println("adding child");
                                    tr.addView(child);
                                    System.out.println("adding table row");
                                     table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

}

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem.

THAnks

Comment: *Where* does it throw that exception?

Comment: specify position here... tr.addView(child); and not same always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iv variable that you are adding, is not been created inside the loop so I imagine is created before... but in the second loop it's added to two different Table Rows.

Answer (score 5):

```
tr.addView(iv,0);
```

Problem is with the `ImageView` (iv), i think, since it is not instantiated inside the loop, so first time it was added to a row, and when you add it again to another row, it doesn't permit, because a view can have only 1 parent.

so i would suggest you to create a new ImageView for every time you loop.

Answer (score 1):

because you are adding same View with new value in each iteration .

initialize imageView iv ,before  tr.addView(iv,0);

```
ImageView in = new ImageView(ctx)
```